# string text to CSV

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I want to format string to CSV. I scraped data from website using BeautifulSoup and get full string.

result Scraped:

```
Business Objective\n
464 Wholesale of household goods\n
Main Business Activities\n
46493 Wholesale of stationery, books, magazines and newspapers\n
```

I tried many way like:

1. `result = re.findall(r'(?==Business Objective=)(.*)(?=Main Business Activities=)', string)`
2. using join

   3.using string replace

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import  time
import re
import numpy
import csv
companyName = "MONUMENT BOOKS CO  LTD"
SourceAppCode = "-- Any register --"
browser = webdriver.Chrome("D:\KHIHORT_PROJECTS\YUON_LOTO\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver")
browser.get('https://www.businessregistration.moc.gov.kh/cambodia-master/relay.html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.businessregistration.moc.gov.kh%2Fcambodia-master%2Fservice%2Fcreate.html%3FtargetAppCode%3Dcambodia-master%26targetRegisterAppCode%3Dcambodia-br-companies%26service%3DregisterItemSearch&target=cambodia-master')
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name='QueryString']")[0].send_keys(companyName)
time.sleep(0.5)
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[@name='SourceAppCode']")[0].send_keys(SourceAppCode)
time.sleep(0.5)
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a[3]")[0].click()
time.sleep(0.5)
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='registerItemSearch-results-page-line-ItemBox-resultLeft-viewMenu appMenu appMenuItem appMenuDepth0 noSave appItemSearchResult viewInstanceUpdateStackPush appReadOnly appIndex0']")[0].click()
time.sleep(0.5)
ww=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[7]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]")
time.sleep(0.5)
```

My expected result is:

```
Business Objective,Main Business Activities
464 Wholesale of household goods,"46493 Wholesale of stationery, books, magazines and newspapers"
"581 Publishing of books, periodicals and other publishing activities","58110 Publishing of books, brochures and other publications(2)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use seleniums wait function rather than sleep. But You can pull out those rows, throw into a dataframe, then write as csv:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import  time
import re
import numpy
import csv
companyName = "MONUMENT BOOKS CO  LTD"
SourceAppCode = "-- Any register --"
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
browser.get('https://www.businessregistration.moc.gov.kh/cambodia-master/relay.html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.businessregistration.moc.gov.kh%2Fcambodia-master%2Fservice%2Fcreate.html%3FtargetAppCode%3Dcambodia-master%26targetRegisterAppCode%3Dcambodia-br-companies%26service%3DregisterItemSearch&target=cambodia-master')
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name='QueryString']")[0].send_keys(companyName)
time.sleep(0.5)
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[@name='SourceAppCode']")[0].send_keys(SourceAppCode)
time.sleep(0.5)
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a[3]")[0].click()
time.sleep(0.5)
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='registerItemSearch-results-page-line-ItemBox-resultLeft-viewMenu appMenu appMenuItem appMenuDepth0 noSave appItemSearchResult viewInstanceUpdateStackPush appReadOnly appIndex0']")[0].click()
time.sleep(0.5)
ww=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[7]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]")
time.sleep(0.5) 


soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
ba = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'appRepeaterContent'})[1]

rows = ba.find_all('div',{'class':'appRecordChildren appBlockChildren'})



results = pd.DataFrame()
for row in rows:
    bo = row.find('div',{'class':'appAttrValue'})
    mba = bo.findNext('div',{'class':'appAttrValue'})

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[bo.text, mba.text]], columns=['Business Objective','Main Business Activies'])
    results = results.append(temp_df, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)

results.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results)
                                   Business Objective                             Main Business Activies
0                    464 Wholesale of household goods  46493 Wholesale of stationery, books, magazine...
1   581 Publishing of books, periodicals and other...  58110 Publishing of books, brochures and other...
2   581 Publishing of books, periodicals and other...  58120 Publishing of mailing lists, telephone b...
3   581 Publishing of books, periodicals and other...  58130 Publishing of newspapers, journals, maga...
4   581 Publishing of books, periodicals and other...  58190 Publishing of catalogs, photos, engravin...
5                 469 Non-specialized wholesale trade  46900 Wholesale of a variety of goods without ...
6                    464 Wholesale of household goods  46431 Wholesale of pharmaceutical and medical ...
7                         521 Warehousing and storage             52100 Warehousing and storage services
8              421 Construction of roads and railways  42101 Construction of streets, roads, bridges ...
9   681 Real estate activities with own or leased ...  68101 Buying, selling, renting and operating o...
10                                854 Other education                     85499 Other education n.e.c(6)
11                                    731 Advertising                               73100 Advertising(1)
12            551 Short term accommodation activities                     55101 Hotels and resort hotels
13  561 Restaurants and mobile food service activi...   56101 Restaurants and restaurant cum night clubs
14     791 Travel agency and tour operator activities                  79110 Travel agency activities(1)
```

Comment: Wow so cool. you made my day. Thank you so much for your answer.
This is the answer that i really need.